# what can I use to replace a large number of

Tags: word-choice

what can I use to replace a large number of or a growing body of? 
I want to say "a large number of studies found something". But I have used this before, I want to change it to other words to describe a lot or many.

Thanks!

Comment: Both *many* and *several* would seem to fit your requirement.

Comment: If you expect to be taken seriously, give actual numbers instead of handwaving.

Comment: "Myriad" and "plethora" are two possibilities, but make sure you understand their definitions and pronunciations, since they are commonly misused and/or mispronounced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Thesaurus.com](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/many) provides good alternatives for this phrase.

The ones I find myself using most often, and the ones I see other people using, are *numerous*, *a myriad*, *countless**, *an endless amount of* *, *a copious amount of*, and last but not least, *many* (which is sometimes too simple of a word).

The ones I have marked with an asterisk are exaggerations because *a large number* doesn't equal an infinite amount, so be cautious with how you use these. However, they are still commonly used, and it is usually understood by the reader that these are simply exaggerations.

Additionally, the two phrases I listed that use *amount* can be rewritten as *an endless number of* and *a copious number of* therefore expanding your options even further.

Answer (score 0):

*Widespread* studies signifies a large number of studies.

*Increasingly* signifies a growing body of.

Comment: _Widespread_ isn't usually used as a quantitative word. It's better used to describe the "reach" of something (e.g., a widespread disease).